# What is a PHP library that will show inline diffs?

Tags: php, diff

I'm looking for a PHP library that will provide me inline diffing between two strings, like this: http://grabby.info/dfe2835f606443757ae7c18404e71781.png.

I'm using xdiff currently, but it's crossing out the entire line when a single word changes, and that's not what I want.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used xdiff for this to highlight changes in the text of an html page. The basic workflow was:

1. escape all HTML entities
2. split HTML tags onto their own lines (append `\n` after the closing `>`)
3. split the resulting text on whitespace (eliminating duplicate whitespace)
4. rejoin the results of the previous split with `\n`as the separator, so now all tags and words are on `separate` lines
5. do the diff with `[xdiff_string_diff()][1]`
6. Patch up the diff output to highlight the additions/deletions with the appropriate tags

not particularly efficient, and very top-heavy on extra wrapping tags if you've got a long sequence of ads/deletions, but it did the job.

Comment: Hmm, I will definitely try this. This seems like a good, creative solution that could definitely solve my problem. Thanks for posting.